# Импортировал старую бд в wordpress, авторизовываюсь, после опять кидает на авторизацию

Tags: php, wordpress, mysql

Что делать, почему так? Логин и пароль все верны. Ошибок нету

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм ширования может стоит посмотреть? Может например в шифре участвовать имя базы или сервера.